# I have prevented default behaviour of form on submit, but it still sending post request automatically to current url

Tags: reactjs, forms

```
 <form
              className="login"
              onSubmit={e => {
                alert('hey getting called')
                e.preventDefault()
                this.authorizeUser(e)
              }}
            >
              <input
                type="text"
                name="email"
                onChange={e => this.handleInputChange(e)}
                value={email}
                className="login-input"
                placeholder="Email Adress"
                autoFocus
              />
              <input
                type="password"
                name="password"
                onChange={e => this.handleInputChange(e)}
                value={password}
                className="login-input"
                placeholder="Password"
              />
              <button
                type="submit"
                style={{height: '37px', float: 'left'}}
                className="login-button"
              >
                Login
              </button>
            </form>
```

code is not reaching up to alert statement.
instead i see url changes to ->
http://localhost:3000/signin?email=testUSer%40abx.in&password=1234567 and page gets refreshed

This issue is happening after i updated react version from 16.9 to 17.0.0.

**UPDATE**

When i add the listener via add event listener inside `componentDidMount()` then suddenly it started working as expected!

still wonder why the `onSubmit` directly on form didn't work

Comment: Have you tried calling `e.preventDefault()` before the `alert()`? Alert is kind of special, in that it pauses your function execution, but other events continue to run. So calling alert() before the preventDefault() will branch the execution and allow the form element enough time to handle the default behavior.

Comment: yes i have, but still the same

Comment: When i add the listener via add event listener inside componentDidMount() then suddenly it started working again!

Comment: I tested your code, it worked correctly, could you include other parts of your component in the question.